# How to build a dll only with func's declaration, and the implementation is in main pro on MAC

Tags: c, macos, dll

How to build a dll only with func's declaration, and the implementation is in main pro.

I am trying to build a dll, with a register func called in init func of the dll. It can build and run perfectly on Linux platform. But it report errors with the exactly same code and compilation method. Here are the codes and gcc compilation cmd.

dll.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
typedef struct test {
    int i;
    void (*echo_fun)(struct test *p);
}Test;
 
void my_register(Test *p);
 
static void printf_test(Test *p) {
    printf("i = %d\n", p->i);
}
 
static Test config = {
    .i = 0,
    .echo_fun = printf_test,
};
 
void __attribute__((constructor)) my_init(void) {
    printf("initn");
    my_register(&config);
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
typedef struct my_test {
    int i;
    void (* echo_fun)(struct __test *p);
}Test;
 
void my_register(Test *p) {
    p->i = 1;
    p->echo_fun(p);
}
 
int main(void) {
    void *handle = NULL;
    char *myso = “./dll.dylib”;
 
    if((handle = dlopen(myso, RTLD_NOW)) == NULL) {
        printf("dlopen - %sn", dlerror());
        exit(-1);
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

build with:
`gcc -shared -fPIC -nostartfiles -o dll.dylib dll.c`

Here are errors:

```
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -dynamic -dylib -arch x86_64 -platform_version macos 13.0.0 13.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -o dll.dylib -L/usr/local/lib dll.o -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_my_register", referenced from:
      _my_init in dll.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My question is :

1. Why it works perfctly on linux platform, but can't work on MAC?
2. Is it possible to make it build successfully on MAC? How to do it?

Comment: Beware.  Identifiers starting with two consecutive underscore characters are [*reserved identifiers*](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3): "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use. ... If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: Note also "All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.".  Your `_init` violates that.  You're also using identifiers such as `__register`, `__printf()`, `_test`, and `_init` that are very likely to clash with actual identifiers.  Change those and your problem might be solved.

Comment: Pretty much all details of libraries, and especially shared libraries, are system-specific.  It is not at all surprising to find something that works on one system and not another.  This has something to do with the OS itself, but even more to do with the build toolchain.  You`re very likely using the GNU toolchain on Linux, but you're definitely using the Clang / LLVM toolchain on Mac.  It is to be expected that there will be differences.

Comment: There is very likely a way to resolve it on Mac, but Clang's docs are pretty lackluster.  I'm not finding anything helpful there.

Comment: Has changed, but not worked @AndrewHenle